# How can I only show a certain level in a nested list? (Responsive web design)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a responsive page where the mobile view only shows the selected level and its corresponding children, while the desktop view will show all levels and corresponding children. Is this even possible?

**This is what it should look like at the top level:**

*On mobile & desktop (level 0):*

- Top Level (selected & show)

  - Second Level (show)
  - Second Level (show)

**Now this is where it gets a bit tricky:**

*On mobile (level 1):*

- Top Level (hide)

  - Second Level (selected & show)

    - Third Level (show)
  - Second Level (hide)

*On desktop (level 1):*

- Top Level (show)

  - Second Level (selected & show)

    - Third Level (show)
  - Second Level (show)

I have tried using `visibility: hidden`, however this doesn't work exactly because the hidden elements still interrupt the flow of the DOM. Thoughts?

*EDIT: Here's some code to show the problem (though it is essentially the same as the rendered markup above)* On a desktop breakpoint I would want all of the below markup to show:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Top Level</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Second Level</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
                    <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Second Level</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, on a mobile breakpoint, I would only want this snippet of markup to show:

```
<li>
    <span>Second Level</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
        <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you provide a visual representation of what you're envisioning?

Comment: use @media queries for different screen sizes and use display: hidden. You can accomplish the same thing w/ js but I think css will suffice.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? In a typical nested menu if you hide the parent (Top Level) the children will also be hidden because they are nested inside the parent. But it depends on your markup

Comment: @zgood thats exactly the question I'm trying to figure out. It's easy to say only show the selected & its children, but the challenge is figuring out how to hide that top level without ending up hiding everything under it too (and displaying nothing at all)

Comment: The simplest way to achieve this is to have two separate DOM structures, and show/hide them using @media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibiility: hidden` makes an element invisible, but it still exists in the DOM taking up space.

You want `display:none;`.  That comepletly removes it from the DOM.

EDIT:  Now that I understand better.  It is possible but there will be issues to dead with.  You could hide the `<span>` in the top level list item.  You would obviously need to do something about the padding of the `ul` though.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="hideme">Top Level</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Second Level</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
                    <li><span>Third Level</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Second Level</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width : 768px) {
  .hideme {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj3ykmey/1/)

Comment: @sn3ll the challenge here is `display: none` will not allow any children to be  displayed either.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I am reading the op question.  He says: "I have tried using visibility: hidden, however this doesn't work exactly because the hidden elements still interrupt the flow of the DOM."  Which logically leads me to believe he is targeting the right elements, but they are invisible and not removed.  Others have already stated that op should post code so we can get more detail, saw no reason to repeat that...

Comment: @Tom you really should post your code, its difficult to guess exactly whats going on.  Maybe set the height to 0?